# AVL Tree Nodes (Print)

Tags: c++, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, avl-tree

I'm currently working through AVL trees and am curious why the output (pre order traversal) is only showing two levels of indentation, as if one of the second order nodes is pointing to three separate 3rd level node. I'm note sure if this is an issue with my print function, or the actual code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class BST;

template <class T>
class BSTNode{
    T data;
    BSTNode<T>* parent;
    BSTNode<T>* left;
    BSTNode<T>* right;
    int height;
public:
    BSTNode(T data = T(), BSTNode<T>* parent = nullptr, BSTNode<T>* left = nullptr,
            BSTNode<T>* right = nullptr, int height = 0) : data(data), parent(parent), left(left), right(right), height(height){}
    friend class BST<T>;
    int getSize() const;
};

template <class T>
class BST{
public:
    BSTNode<T>* root = nullptr;
    BST() {}
    ~BST();
    BST(const BST& rhs) {*this = rhs;};
    BST& operator=(const BST& rhs);
    void printPreOrder(BSTNode<T>* p, int indent);
    void insert(T item, BSTNode<T> * & node);
    void remove(BSTNode<T>*& temp); //pass pointer by reference because we will be changing the pointer
    void clear(BSTNode<T>*& root); //clears the entire tree;
    BST<T>* clone(BSTNode<T>* start);
    void rotateRight(BSTNode<T> * & node); //rotate the left child (the left child becomes the parent and parent becomes the right child)
    void rotateLeft(BSTNode<T> * & node); //rotate the right child (the right child becomes the parent and the parent becomes the left child)
    void doubleRotateRight(BSTNode<T> *& node); //same result as rotate right
    void doubleRotateLeft(BSTNode<T> *& node); //same result as rotate left
    int height(BSTNode<T> * node); //return height
    void balance(BSTNode<T> * &node);
};

template <class T>
int BSTNode<T>::getSize() const {
    int count = 1;
    if(left != nullptr){
        count += left->getSize();
    };
    if(right != nullptr){
        count += right->getSize();
    };
    return count;
}
template <class T>
void BST<T>::printPreOrder(BSTNode<T>* p, int indent){
    if(p) {
        if (indent) {
            std::cout << std::setw(indent) << '\t';
        }
        cout<< p->data << "\n ";
        if(p->left) printPreOrder(p->left, indent+2);
        if(p->right) printPreOrder(p->right, indent+2);
    }
}
template <class T>
void BST<T>::insert(T item, BSTNode<T> * & node){
    if(!node){
        node = new BSTNode<T>(item);
    }
    else if(item < node->data){
        insert(item, node->left);
    }
    else{
        insert(item, node->right);
    }
    balance(node);
}
template <class T>
void BST<T>::remove(BSTNode<T>*& temp){
    if(temp->left == nullptr && temp->right == nullptr){
        if(temp->parent == nullptr){
            root = nullptr;
        }
        else if(temp->parent->left == temp){
            temp->parent->left = nullptr;
        }
        else{
            temp->parent->right = nullptr;
        }
        delete temp;
    }
    else if(temp->left == nullptr){ //promote right
        BSTNode<T>* toDelete = temp->right;
        temp->data = toDelete->data;
        temp->left = toDelete->left;
        temp->right = toDelete->right;
        if(temp->left){
            temp->left->parent = temp->left;
        }
        if(temp->right){
            temp->right->parent = temp;
        }
        delete toDelete;
    }
    else if(temp->right == nullptr){ //promote left
        BSTNode<T>* toDelete = temp->left;
        temp->data = toDelete->data;
        temp->left = toDelete->left;
        temp->right = toDelete->right;
        if(temp->left){
            temp->left->parent = temp->left;
        }
        if(temp->right){
            temp->right->parent = temp;
        }
        delete toDelete;
    }
    else{
        BSTNode<T>* maxOfLeft = temp->left;
        while(maxOfLeft){
            maxOfLeft = maxOfLeft->right;
        }
        temp->data = maxOfLeft->data;
        remove(maxOfLeft);
    }
    balance(temp);
}
template <class T>
void BST<T>::clear(BSTNode<T>*& root) {
    if (root) {
        if (root->left) {
            clear(root->left);
        }
        if (root->right) {
            clear(root->right);
        }
        delete root;
    }
    root = nullptr;
};
template <class T>
BST<T>::~BST(){
    clear(root);
}
template <class T>
BST<T>* BST<T>::clone(BSTNode<T>* start){
    if(!start){
        return nullptr;
    }
    else{
        return new BSTNode<T>(start->data, clone(start->left), clone(start->right));
    }
}
template <class T>
BST<T>& BST<T>::operator=(const BST<T>& rhs){
    if(this == &rhs){
        return *this;
    }
    clear(root);
    root = clone(rhs.root);
    return *this;
}
template <class T>
void BST<T>::rotateRight(BSTNode<T> * & node){

    BSTNode<T> * newParent = node->left;
    node->left = newParent->right;
    newParent->right = node;

    node->height = max(height(node->right),height(node->left)) + 1;
    newParent->height = max(height(newParent->left), node->height) + 1;

    node = newParent; //set new root (we can't access newParent outside of this function!)
}
template <class T>
void BST<T>::rotateLeft(BSTNode<T> * & node){

    BSTNode<T> * newParent = node->right;
    node->right = newParent->left;
    newParent->left = node;

    node->height = max(height(node->right), height(node->left)) + 1;
    newParent->height = max(height(newParent->right), node->height) + 1;

    node = newParent; //set new root (we can't access newParent outside of this function!)
}
template <class T>
int BST<T>::height(BSTNode<T> *node){
    if(node){
        return node->height;
    };
    return -1;
}
template <class T>
void BST<T>::doubleRotateRight(BSTNode<T> * &node){
    rotateLeft(node->left);
    rotateRight(node);
}
template<class T>
void BST<T>::doubleRotateLeft(BSTNode<T> * &node){
    rotateRight(node->right);
    rotateLeft(node);
}
template<class T>
void BST<T>::balance(BSTNode<T> * &node){
    if(!node){
        return;
    }
    if(height(node->left) > height(node->right) + 1){
        if(height(node->left->left) >= height(node->left->right)){
            rotateRight(node);
        }
        else{
            doubleRotateRight(node);
        };
    };
    if(height(node->right) > height(node->left) + 1){
        if(height(node->right->right) >= height(node->right->left)){
            rotateLeft(node);
        }
        else{
            doubleRotateLeft(node);
        }
    }
    node->height = max(height(node->right), height(node->left)) + 1;
}

int main() {

    vector<int>data = {5, 3, 4, 2, 1, 2, 6, 7};
    BST<int> test;

    for(int r : data){
        test.insert(r, test.root);
    }

    test.printPreOrder(test.root,0);
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output I am getting:

```
3
    2
        1
        2
    5
        4
        6
        7
```

From my understanding, I should be getting the following output:

```
3
    2
        1
        2
    5
        4
        6
           7
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use tabs.

Consider this example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {

    for (int indent=0;indent<5;++indent) {
        if (indent) {
            std::cout << std::setw(indent) << "\t" << "tabs" << "\n";
            std::cout << std::setw(indent) << " " << "spaces" << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Possible output is:

```
    tabs
 spaces
    tabs
  spaces
    tabs
   spaces
    tabs
    spaces
```